# PLA for Dactyl Manuform print | Which material for printing the shell

Tags: pla, filament, diy-3d-printer, material, filament-choice

I bought PLA Wood for my planned Dactyl Manuform. But now the question is whether this will melt or deform in the sun.

I live in Germany, where we reach some days at times 32 °C. However, the keyboard will stand on my desk and will also be directly exposed to the sun.

Now I am worried that this could already be deformed after a few days/months.

Should I rather buy PETG or ABS and print the parts with it?

Or does anyone have experience with PLA in the sun?

Filament: Giantarm PLA Wood

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment directly on Giantarm PLA Wood, but I can give two endpoints: I have an antenna sleeve (for the amateur radio antenna on my car, to keep it from folding when it shouldn't) printed from black generic PLA; it stands in direct sun and has so far withstood *air temperature* of 37 °C (in direct sun, remember) without any visible deformation -- and I printed a cell phone holder for the interior of my car which failed, softening and sagging under its own weight when it was nowhere close to that temperature outside (but the car was in the sun, so the interior likely approached 50 °C).

Based on that, I would expect PLA to remain fine as long as the temperature of the material stays below about 50 °C, which is its glass transition (approximately).  If your office gets warm enough for the keyboard to reach that temperature (even in direct sun), you'll have multiple other issues with computer overheating, plants dying, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed reply. 
I will try my luck with PLA.
It should never reach 50° in my office :D

Comment: Just so you don't try to use the keyboard in a sauna...  ;)